# How to use Jasmine.js spy on a required function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, jasmine-node

I have this code (Node.js):

File: utils.js

```
// utils.js
const foo = () => {
    // ....
}

const bar = () => {
    // ....
}

module.exports = { foo, bar }
```

File: myModule.js

```
// myModule.js
const {
    foo,
    bar
} = require('./utils');

const bizz = () => {
    let fooResult = foo()
    return bar(fooResult)
}

module.exports = { bizz }
```

File: myModule.spec.js

```
// myModule.spec.js
const { bizz } = require('./myModule');
describe('myModule', () => {

    it('bizz should return bla bla bla', () => {
        let foo = jasmine.createSpy('foo').and.returnValue(true)
        let bar = jasmine.createSpy('bar').and.callFake((data) => {
            expect(date).toBeTrue();
            return 'fake-data'
        })

        expect(bizz()).toBe('fake-data')
    })
})
```

I'm trying to test `bizz` using spies on `foo` and `bar` functions but it's not working well.

Can anyone explain to me how to create spies on these functions with the purpose to test bizz??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
You just need to require `utils` to `spyOn` first, then require `myModule`. The following test will pass.

```
const utils = require('./utils');

// myModule.spec.js
describe('myModule', () => {
  it('bizz should return bla bla bla', () => {
    const fooSpy = spyOn(utils, 'foo').and.returnValue(true);
    const barSpy = spyOn(utils, 'bar').and.callFake(data => {
      expect(data).toBeTrue();
      return 'fake-data';
    });

    const { bizz } = require('./myModule'); // Import myModule after you added the spyOn

    expect(bizz()).toBe('fake-data');

    expect(fooSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(barSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: It works! But how can I overwrite the spy for the next test? On the next test I want test the result of bizz function if foo return false. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it's not possible. https://github.com/mjackson/expect/issues/169